# How do I sort this python list by the number?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a number of people based on their score, and then print out the top 3 people and their scores. Right now it looks like this:

```
List = ['A 3.0', 'B 4.0', 'C 13.0'] #My list
Sorted = sorted(List, key = lambda item:item.split(" ")[1], reverse = True) #Sorting script
print("Top three scorers and their average goal scores.", "\n", Sorted[0], "\n", Sorted[1], "\n", Sorted[2]) #Printing function
```

But when I run it, it prints this:

```
B 4.0
A 3.0
C 13.0
```

But '13.0' is not at all smaller than '3.0' and '4.0'. I want the actual highest number to be at the top, does anyone have the answer, I am using 'python 3.4.4'.

I am thinking that it might be sorting by the '1' and then by the '3' in the '13.0' as if separate characters, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: that's because you're sorting it alphabetically, convert the string to a number with int(item.split(" ")[1]).

Comment: @SilentMonk yes, youre right, it should be float(), was just thinking on numbers and the first that came was int :P

Comment: The answers to this question are great workarounds for a problem you would not have if you used a more sensible data format. Why would you want to represent a `person` and a `score` as a space-delimited string? Use a `tuple(str, float)` and your problem goes away...

Answer (score 2):

Change the second line as below.. (the split item is a string. convert that into a float, it will work.)

```
Sorted = sorted(List, key = lambda item:float(item.split(" ")[1]), reverse = True) #Sorting script
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to float to have numeric ordering like this:

```
Sorted = sorted(List, key = lambda item:float(item.split(" ")[1]), reverse = True) #Sorting script
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specific about using lists,I suggest you to do create an object/tuple of something similar to the below

```
 new_tuple= [('A', 3.0),('B', 4.0),('C', 13.0)]#create an object
 Sorted = sorted(tuple, key = lambda new:new[1], reverse = True) #Sorting script
 print("Top three scorers and their average goal scores.", "\n", Sorted[0], "\n", Sorted[1], "\n", Sorted[2]) #Printing function
```

Hope this helps.All the best :)